# Follow-up to how to get an Integer as result

Tags: java, android

I asked a question [How to get an Integer as result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188369/how-to-get-an-integer-as-result)

The suggested solution with `decimalFormat` works, but my problem is that I want my data not only to be presented as `##.0` but to be like this, because in the end of my program I use them.  So I want to be exactly in that type; otherwise I get the wrong final number.  Any  ideas?

EDIT:

let me be more specific. i get 12,344 from my first calc, 14,4566 from my second and 18,5644 from my third.that makes a sum 45.365.Now,if i do then 12,3 , 14,4 and 18,5 the sum is 45.2...thats the point of my answer.i want to have 45.365 at the end and not 45.2

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Why can't you just output the value using `decimalFormat` at the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get an Integer as result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188369/how-to-get-an-integer-as-result)

Comment: I suggest you should stick to your original question where the context is. I have voted to close this one.

Comment: i m saying that i have asked it before,but i have accepted an answer and i want something more now..:)

Comment: @EJP - I think this is a significantly different question.  Changing the original question would (IMO) not serve the overall goals of SO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a design issue with your app.

On the one hand, you want to display the results to the user with 1 digit after the decimal point.

In the other hand, you actually want to keep the extra precision and use it for follow-up calculations.

I would argue that this is a poor user interface model.  IMO, the numbers that the user sees should be the numbers that go into the calculations.  This means you should either:

1. show the user more digits after the DP in the first place (or at least give a visual indication that there are more digits), or
2. do the calculations using the rounded / truncated values ... as displayed to the user.

Once you have figured out a consistent user interface model, the required implementation approach should be much clearer to you.

Comment: the decimal point i only use it to firstly print the numbers to the user..then,i make my final calculation with the original numbers,i got a result and i print it with a new decimal..my thought is how i will convert my number in the format i want to??if i do it,there will be no reason to use decimal..hope i m understandable..

Comment: I understood that.  What I'm saying is that your user interface model is wrong.  If you use a consistent user interface model, you won't have this problem.  Or at least, you will understand how to implement it.

Comment: i m really glad for your help..could you please be more spesific on your answer..?i m new to android and java developement...

Comment: I cannot be more specific until you say whether you are going to choose option 1. or option 2. in your user interface design.

Comment: which way is the better one?think that the 1rst is ok,but i have no problem to use the 2nd too..

Comment: OK.  The simple way it to just use a DecimalFormat string that gives / allows lots of digits after the decimal point.